# ReactNative add Gradle Dependency using Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I am very new to Mobile Development especially with the use of Android Studio and Java (but i'm familiar with the language already as i came from C#). But the challenge is i don't yet how to configure the project itself unlike what i can do in VS.

Basically i am trying to include a **downloaded** SDK, the package looked like it is the same as my project (contains Gradle, etc, etc, so i've thought this is Gradle Project).

**What i have tried**
is going to `file` -> `Project Structure` -> `Dependencies` -> `Add Dependency`. Which is basically including a `Gradle Project` from the options.

It went a-okay but i'm not aware yet it this was right? I checked the Docs from android studio and included the dependency in my Gradle.

It goes like this: `implementation project(":MyDownloadedProject")`

I know this is pretty simple but i've been checking out stuffs for a long time already but unable to find any useful resource.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Add build dependencies with autolinking or by manually adding to build.gradle

see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies